# Middleware priority not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm stuck on something which I'm pretty sure is quite basic.. but somehow I can't get it to work.

I created a middleware to set the locale of my website depending on the user's choice (his choice is registered in the database under 'locale' column). What I do is that I check is user is logged-in, if he is I use his locale, if not I default to English.

For some reason, my middleware never "sees" the user as logged-in and always defaults to English. I've output the result of Auth::check() to a log and indeed this always returns false, even if the user is actually logged-in.

I suppose this has to do with this Middleware being executed before the Auth one.. I've tried to change the priority in the Kernel file but that still doesn't work.. any idea?

My middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SetLocale {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

      if(Auth::check()) {
        $locale = Auth::user()->locale;
      } else {
        $locale = 'en';
      }
      \App::setLocale($locale);
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My route ('auth' is the default auth middleware, 'checkProjectPermission:read' checks if the user logged in has permission to access this project)

```
Route::prefix('client')->middleware(['auth','checkRoomPermission:read'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('{project_id}/checklist', 'ProjectController@accessChecklist')->name('checklist');
}
```

My Kernel.php file :

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class
];

protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class
];
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the route, the middleware assigned to that route (such as web/api/auth, etc), and the middleware definition in your `Kernel.php` file.

Comment: Added these in the original post - forgot to precise the route is web though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding `SetLocale` to your global middleware. The `global` middleware does not `start a session` and therefore you have no access to session based data - such as the user.

If you take a look at the `web` middleware provided by laravel (cleaned up for brevity)

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        EncryptCookies::class,
        AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        StartSession::class,
        ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        SubstituteBindings::class
    ]
]
```

You'll see why the any middleware added to `web` middleware will have access to the `auth` class, because it injects `StartSession`.

If you want to access session-based-data, then you'll need to make sure `StartSession` is booted.

**DO NOT** just add `StartSession` to your global middleware or you're going to have a bad time. Instead, add it to your `auth` middleware, and add the `SetLocale` after `StartSession`.

**Edit**

Note that if you're using `Web Middleware` you must add `SetLocale` to that `Middleware Group` as well.

The priority is only a `nsort` where it reorders the `middleware` applied to a current request based on the existence of the middleware in the `middlewarePriority` array.

Simplified: If the middleware is not in the middleware group for the route request, the middleware priority means nothing.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy - I thought that the global middleware would apply to the "web" routes (on top of those defined in "web") but apparently that's not the case. Working like a charm now.